# Is there a way in SQL to Dismiss an update in a trigger if some conditions are met?

Tags: sql

What I want to do is ON UPDATE, when a trigger is excecuting, check if a condtion is met.
If the condition is not met I want to dismiss the update that caused the trigger and prevent if from happaning.

for example:
In a table with a "name"(primary key) field and a "value" field.
lets assume that the record (john, 200) is already in the table
I try to update the record to (john, 140)
in the trigger, I want to check if the given value (in this example 140) is lower than 185.
if so, I don't want the value to be updated to 140, I want the vlaue to stay 200.

is there a way of doing that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: `SQL` is just  a query language, it's ***NOT*** the name of a DBMS product. Especially triggers are not defined by the standard and therefor completely DBMS dependent. You have to state your DBMS otherwise this question cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to achieve what you need is to use [Check Constraint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_constraint). If you use Check Constraints,  the error will be returned on invalid value update and update will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Add an if condition in the trigger code and it will update the column if this condition is met.